# Input text while running puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to automate form filling in one site. but the problem is, that site has an captcha. So Is there any way that when the login page is showing, I can enter the captcha manually in the command prompt like `Console.ReadLine();` from C#. Is there any similar function available in puppeteer?

Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
    await page.goto('https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search');
    await page.click('#loginText');
    await page.type('#userId','xxxxxx');
    await page.type('#pwd','xxxxxx');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'varanjith.png'});
})();
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html not suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enter the captcha in the command line, you can use built-in `readline` module

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const readline = require('readline');

async function readLine() {

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        rl.question('Enter captcha: ', (answer) => {
          rl.close();
          resolve(answer)
        });
    })
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
    await page.goto('https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search');
    await page.click('#loginText');
    await page.type('#userId','xxxxxx');
    await page.type('#pwd','xxxxxx');

    const captcha = await readLine();

    await page.type('#nlpAnswer', captcha)

    await page.screenshot({path: 'varanjith.png'});
})();
```

---

**Original Answer:**

If you want to enter the captcha in the UI and once it's filled continue with the script you can use: [`page.waitForFunction`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
    await page.goto('https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search');
    await page.click('#loginText');
    await page.type('#userId','xxxxxx');
    await page.type('#pwd','xxxxxx');

    console.log('Waiting for captcha');
    await page.waitForFunction(() => {
        const captchaInput = document.getElementById('nlpAnswer');
        return captchaInput && 
           captchaInput.value && 
           captchaInput !== document.activeElement
    })
    console.log('Captcha filled');

    await page.screenshot({path: 'varanjith.png'});
})();
```

Breakdown:

- The captcha input in that particular page is: `'nlpAnswer'`

  ```
  const captchaInput = document.getElementById('nlpAnswer');
  ```
- Wait until `captchaInput` is available, it has value & it's not focused anymore

```js
return captchaInput && 
       captchaInput.value && 
       captchaInput !== document.activeElement
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Estradiaz mentioned. You can use [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) with some promise boilerplate:

```js
(async () => {

  // Launches browser
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
  await page.goto('https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search');
  await page.click('#loginText');
  await page.type('#userId','xxxxxx');
  await page.type('#pwd','xxxxxx');

  const readline = require('readline');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  let fulfill;
  const answerPromise = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);
  rl.question('Enter the Captcha: ', (answer) => {
    fulfill(answer);
    rl.close();
  });
  const answer = await answerPromise;
  console.log(answer);
  await page.type('#nlpAnswer',answer);
  await page.waitFor(5000);
  await page.screenshot({path: 'varanjith.png'});
  browser.close();
})();
```